# find -name with multiple filenames using shell variable

Tags: bash, shell, find

I have a `find` command that finds files with name matching multiple patterns mentioned against the `-name` parameter

```
find -L . \( -name "SystemOut*.log" -o -name "*.out" -o -name "*.log" -o -name "javacore*.*" \)
```

This finds required files successfully at the command line. What I am looking for is to use this command in a shell script and join this with a `tar` command to create a tar of all log files. So, in a script I do the following:

```
LIST="-name \"SystemOut*.log\" -o -name \"*.out\" -o -name \"*.log\" -o -name \"javacore*.*\" "
find -L . \( ${LIST} \)
```

This does not print files that I am looking for.

First - why this script is not functioning like the command?  Once it does, can I club it with `cpio` or similar to create a `tar` in one shot?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like `find` fails to match `*` in patterns from unquoted variables. This syntax works for me (using bash arrays):

```
LIST=( -name \*.tar.gz )
find . "${LIST[@]}"
```

Your example would become the following:

```
LIST=( -name SystemOut\*.log -o -name \*.out -o -name \*.log -o -name javacore\*.\* )
find -L . \( "${LIST[@]}" \)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
eval "find -L . \( ${LIST} \)"
```

Comment: But **[eval is evil!!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17529220/1765658)**

Comment: evil is as evil does

Comment: Comming late to this SO thread. Have a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68698997/1765658) !

Answer (score 1):

When you have a long list of file names you use, you may want to try the following syntax instead:

```
# List of file patterns
Pat=( "SystemOut*.log"
"*.out"
"*.log"
"javacore*.*" )

# Loop through each file pattern and build a 'find' string
find $startdir \( -name $(printf -- $'\'%s\'' "${Pat[0]}") $(printf -- $'-o -name \'%s\' ' "${Pat[@]:1}") \)
```

That method constructs the argument sequentially using elements from a list, which tends to work better (at least in my recent experiences).

You can use find's `-exec` option to pass the results to an archiving program:

```
find -L . \( .. \) -exec tar -Af archive.tar {} \;
```

Comment: +1 for the construct, this does not get results from with in a script, though.

Comment: @ringbearer- Can you explain what you mean by "does not get results from within a script"?  I use that particular code snippet in several different scripts.

Comment: Following error:"find: paths must precede expression" - Using the following: GNU find version 4.2.27
Features enabled: D_TYPE O_NOFOLLOW(enabled) LEAF_OPTIMISATION SELINUX and here is the find construct printed via `echo` : `find /opt/appserver \( -name *.out -o -name "*.log core*.*" -o -name "javacore*.*" -o -name "heapdump*.*" -name "server.log_*"  \) `

Comment: Oops, it looks like I quoted the wildcard expressions incorrectly (I should have used single-quotes instead of double-quotes).  See my updated answer for a correctly-quoted version.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an eval and xargs,

```
eval "find -L . \( $LIST \) " | xargs tar cf 1.tar
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LIST="-name SystemOut*.log -o -name *.out -o -name *.log -o -name javacore*.*"
```

The wildcards are already quoted and you don't need to quote them again. Moreover, here

```
LIST="-name \"SystemOut*.log\""
```

the inner quotes are preserved and `find` will get them as a part of the argument.

Answer (score 0):

#### Building `-name` list for `find` command

Here is a proper way to do this:

```
cmd=();for p in \*.{log,tmp,bak} .debug-\*;do [ "$cmd" ] && cmd+=(-o);cmd+=(-name "$p");done
```

Or

```
cmd=()
for p in \*.{log,tmp,bak,'Spaced FileName'} {.debug,.log}-\* ;do
    [ "$cmd" ] && cmd+=(-o)
    cmd+=(-name "$p")
done
```

You could dump you `$cmd` array:

```
declare -p cmd
declare -a cmd=([0]="-name" [1]="*.log" [2]="-o" [3]="-name" [4]="*.tmp" [5]="-o"
     [6]="-name" [7]="*.bak" [8]="-o" [9]="-name" [10]="*.Spaced FileName" 
     [11]="-o" [12]="-name" [13]=".debug-*" [14]="-o" [15]="-name" [16]=".log-*")
```

Then now you could

```
find [-L] [/path] \( "${cmd[@]}" \)
```

As

```
find \( "${cmd[@]}" \)
```

(Nota: if no path is submited, current path `.` is default)

```
find /home/user/SomeDir \( "${cmd[@]}" \)

find -L /path -type f \( "${cmd[@]}" \)
```